# plugin install through proxy

Tags: elasticsearch, neo4j, proxy, graphaware

I am trying to install Graph-Aided Search to integrate Neo4j with ElasticSearch (2.3.1) as shown [here](https://github.com/graphaware/graph-aided-search#elasticsearch-231). But when I try this command line:

```
plugin install com.graphaware.es/graph-aided-search/2.3.2.0
```

I get errors:

```
plugin install com.graphaware.es/graph-aided-search/2.3.2.0
-> Installing com.graphaware.es/graph-aided-search/2.3.2.0...
Trying https://download.elastic.co/com.graphaware.es/graph-aided-search/graph-aided-search-2.3.2.0.zip ...
Trying https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/graphaware/es/graph-aided-search/2.3.2.0/graph-aided-search-2.3.2.0.zip ...
Trying https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/content/com/graphaware/es/graph-aided-search/2.3.2.0/graph-aided-search-2.3.2.0.zip ...
Trying https://github.com/com.graphaware.es/graph-aided-search/archive/2.3.2.0.zip ...
Trying https://github.com/com.graphaware.es/graph-aided-search/archive/master.zip ...
ERROR: failed to download out of all possible locations..., use --verbose to get detailed information
```

And this when I add `--verbose` for more details:

```
plugin install com.graphaware.es/graph-aided-search/2.3.2.0 --verbose
-> Installing com.graphaware.es/graph-aided-search/2.3.2.0...
Trying https://download.elastic.co/com.graphaware.es/graph-aided-search/graph-aided-search-2.3.2.0.zip ...
Failed: SocketTimeoutException[connect timed out]
Trying https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/graphaware/es/graph-aided-search/2.3.2.0/graph-aided-search-2.3.2.0.zip ...
Failed: SocketTimeoutException[connect timed out]
Trying https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/content/com/graphaware/es/graph-aided-search/2.3.2.0/graph-aided-search-2.3.2.0.zip ...
Failed: SocketTimeoutException[connect timed out]
Trying https://github.com/com.graphaware.es/graph-aided-search/archive/2.3.2.0.zip ...
Failed: SocketTimeoutException[connect timed out]
Trying https://github.com/com.graphaware.es/graph-aided-search/archive/master.zip ...
Failed: SocketTimeoutException[connect timed out]
ERROR: failed to download out of all possible locations..., use --verbose to get detailed information
```

I looked for that error on google and I found that it might be because of the proxy, and since I am working behind a proxy I tried something that basically worked for others. This is the command line that I tried to install the plugin through proxy:

```
C:\dev\elasticsearch-2.3.1\bin> plugin -Dhttps.proxyHost=http://example.test.fr -Dhttps.proxyPort=3128 -Dhttps.proxyUser=SomeUser -Dhttps.proxyPassword=Password install com.graphaware.es/graph-aided-search/2.3.2.0
```

But still it didn't work, and I am still getting the same error. I forced the authentification to the proxy on Internet Explorer, something that usually works for me when I install packages with `Maven`. However, in that case it didn't work.

I am struggling to integrate my Neo4j database with ElasticSearch, I have been trying that for 4days now and it is taking all my time and cannot work without making this integration with success.

I really appreciate any help or clarification to resolve this error. Thank you.

**[UPDATE]**

When I try to replace the path, it is still not working. I've tried this command line:

```
  plugin install C:\dev\graph-aided-search-master\target\releases\graph-aided‌​-search-2.4.1.4-SNAP‌​SHOT.zip
```

and I got this error message:

```
 -> Installing C:\dev\graph-aided-search-master\target\releases\graph-aided‌​-search-2.4.1.4-SNAP‌​SHOT.zip... 
 ERROR: Invalid prefix or suffix
```

I put the graph-aided-search Zip file in the same folder as plugin file, so in `C:\dev\elasticsearch-2.3.1\bin`. Then I tried with the relative path, and I got this message:

```
> plugin install graph-aided-search-2.4.1.4-SNAPSHOT.zip --verbose
-> Installing graph-aided-search-2.4.1.4-SNAPSHOT.zip...
Trying https://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/release/org/elasticsearch/plugin/graph-aided-search-2.4.1.4-SNAPSHOT.zip/2.3.1/graph-aided-search-2.4.1.4-SNAPSHOT.zip-2.3.1.zip ...
Failed: SocketTimeoutException[connect timed out]
ERROR: failed to download out of all possible locations..., use --verbose to get detailed information
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the plugin manually from the MavenRepository

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.graphaware.es/graph-aided-search

Comment: Which version should I download? I have Elasticsearch (2.3.1) and Neo4j-community-edition(3.1.4). And can you please tell me where excatly should I put the plugin?

Comment: I guess I should download version `2.3.2.0` since I have Elasticsearch `2.3.1`.
But then instead of doing: `$ES_HOME/bin/plugin install com.graphaware.es/graph-aided-search/2.3.2.0` 
should I do `$ES_HOME/bin/plugin install Path/to/plugin/graph-aided-search/2.3.2.0` ? If this what I have to do, it's not working. Or should I only copy it in some folder without installing it?

Comment: It is explained here : https://github.com/graphaware/graph-aided-search#build-from-source . You should use version 2.3.1.0

Comment: What other question ?

Comment: But then instead of doing: `$ES_HOME/bin/plugin install com.graphaware.es/graph-aided-search/2.3.2.0` should I do `$ES_HOME/bin/plugin install Path/to/plugin/graph-aided-search/2.3.2.0` ? If this what I have to do, it's not working. Or should I only copy it in some folder without installing it?

Comment: `$ES_HOME/bin/plugin install file:///path/to/project/graph-aided-search/target/releases/graph-aided-search-2.X.X.0.zip`, replace the path to where is the jar

Comment: When I try it, it is still not working. I try this command line:
`plugin install C:\dev\graph-aided-search-master\target\releases\graph-aided-search-2.4.1.4-SNAPSHOT.zip` and I get this error message `-> Installing C:\dev\graph-aided-search-master\target\releases\graph-aided-search-2.4.1.4-SNAPSHOT.zip...
ERROR: Invalid prefix or suffix`

Comment: Please take a look on the **UPDATE** part

Comment: why 2.4.1.4 ? You should use version 2.3.1.0 for ES 2.3.1, also you miss the file:/// before the path

Comment: Thank you so much. It is now installed with success. But I'm struggling to define the indexes with curl. Please see **Configuration**

Comment: It was a matter of just reading carefully what I was writing and the link I pointed. Please open a new question for the indexes

Comment: My bad! Thank you. I'll open another question for the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is this one:

```
plugin install com.graphaware.es/graph-aided-search/2.3.2.0 -DproxyHost=exampleHost -DproxyPort=portNumber
```

It is working now!